# Отображение формы Django

Tags: django, django-template, django-urls, django-view

Не понимаю как реализовать сбор данных из формы на простом сайте.
Алгоритм следующий:

1. Получаем site.ru из `url`, через общий `ulrs.py` по `''` пустой ссылке подключаем основное приложение

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('',include('Offer.urls')),
       path('blog/',include('blog.urls')),
       ]
   ```
2. Далее по urls.py `''` пустому запросу подключается `FBV` рендер страницы `info.html` который наследуется(extends) от `base.html`, в котором включён(include) `mailto.html`; Такая же логика при переходе по ссылке к contacts.html

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.info, name="info"),
       path('contacts', views.contacts, name="contacts"),
       path('', views.sent_OfferMail, name="sentmail"),
   ]
   ```

Вот `views.py`

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from .forms import Offers_MailForm


    def info(request):
        return render(request, 'Offer/info.html')

    def contacts(request):
        return render(request, 'Offer/contacts.html')

    def sent_OfferMail(request):
        form = Offers_MailForm

        data = {'form':form}

        return render(request, 'Offer/mailto.html', data)
```

Пробовал: добавлять в urls.py ещё один пустой запрос (как в примере выше), не работает;
А если ставить его выше `views.urls` то не грузится главная `/info.html`, что логично для python. Зато отлично отрабатывает форма и она отображается исправно. Это должно как-то подталкивать на решение, но у меня тупик;
То же самое и через `Class Based Views` в частности `FormView`

Я хочу без конкретной ссылки чтоб работал шаблон `mailto.html`, но не понимаю как ему сделать view который будет отрабатываться при любом адресе в url строке.

Более подробно код на моём [GitHub](https://github.com/ChehST/ChehSite)

Может проблема с самим шаблоном `mailto.html`

```
<form method="post" class="row">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Ваш Email, чтобы я cмог вам ответить</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Все данные защищены и не передаются третим лицам</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group field-crq_msg required has-error">
      <label class="control-label" for="crq_msg">Напечатайте ваше сообщение:</label>
      <textarea id="crq_msg" class="form-control" name="crq_msg" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-3">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

по сути шаблон грузится, но форма от DTL {{теги}}, явно связываются только если в `url` дать отдельную ссылку, но тогда форма будет только по ней работать, а я хочу с каждого существующего `url` принимать данные. Но появятся ещё страницы куда я захочу сделать
`{% include 'mailt.to' %}`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вам нужно. Хотите, чтобы при любом адресе в url строке ,несовпадающим уже с существующими, у вас открывался sentmail?

Comment: `mailto.html` включается(include) на разных html страницах и висит на разных состояниях url строки. Но форма работает и подключается, если вывести только как отдельную страницу со своим url